# Late 1960s/ Early 1970s SciFi Comic Story with a character reliving a single day

Tags: story-identification, comics

Trying to identify a story I read in a Marvel-type comic book, late 60s or early 70s. In the story the main character was trapped to live the same day, over and over again.  Like an early take on the film 'Groundhog Day'.  Any ideas?

Comment: This one? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91796/short-story-where-a-man-discovers-hes-living-in-a-fake-world Or, a comic based on it of course.

Comment: Or a graphic version of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94553/unpleasant-uses-of-replicator-3d-printer ?