# SF short story about a "Groundhog Day" kind of party that repeats itself forever

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is probably a tough one. It's a short story I read in an SF anthology (of American stories translated in French). It must have been written in the 60s or 70s.

It's about a sort of "time loop", where people are "stuck" in a one night moment, a wild party that repeats itself forever come each new day - which is in fact not a new day, but the repetition of that one same night. Everybody can get wild and crazy and careless, because there are no consequences, everything is back to where it was the next day.

As far as I remember, there isn't much of a big twist, just the main character realizing finally what's going on and that he's also stuck in that forever repeating moment. And that he can have a blast too. But the writing was very vivid, that's why I'm trying to track it down.

Sounds familiar to anybody ? Thanks :)

EDIT : apparently a similar (and much more accurate...) question was already asked, and answered, about this story :
[Unpleasant Uses of Replicator/3D Printer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94553/unpleasant-uses-of-replicator-3d-printer)
But I feel my entry would still be useful for somebody searching through the "time loop" and "forever party" angles (which is what I remembered), and not "duplicators".

Comment: If this were a novel, I'd suspect David Gerrold's *The Man Who Folded Himself* -- in which the protagonist returns via time machine to the same party which runs for months or years, with different ages of the protagonist (older as the party gets longer).

Comment: Isn't there a chapter about something like that in one of the *Hitchhiker's Guide...* books? Arthur ends up at that party and runs into Trillian randomly?

Comment: @ToddWilcox is thinking of Milliways, the Restaurant at the End of the Universe.  It offers a sumptuous dinner as the universe winks out of existence outside. Afterwards, it goes back in time to show the same event again for the next dinner guests.

Comment: @VBartilucci No I'm not. It's some building floating on a planet and the party is on the rooftop. I think it's in the same book where Arthur learns to fly while running down a mountain fleeing falling boulders. Found it: https://sites.google.com/site/h2g2theguide/Index/l/379605 But it's not the answer to the question because The Longest Party Ever Held does not have the "no consequences" aspect in the question.

Comment: Ah, that'd be The Longest Party Ever Held, now into its fourth generation, and still no one shows any signs of leaving.  It's not traveling in time, but it does fly.

Comment: Thanks for all these ideas, but so far it's none of those. It's a very short story, probably not even very famous. There is no special setup  - like traveling in time, or floating in space. It's really just this "stuck in a time loop" aspect, with that crazy party going on again and again forever. That's why I said it would probably a tough question, because it's pretty flimsy ;)

Comment: Reminds me a tad of... I think Roger Zelazny's "A Very Good Year?"

Comment: @Solinv If you think you've found it, feel free to post it as an answer, instead of editing it into the question.

Comment: @F1Krazy. Sure. Just did. Not very familiar with the mechanics of the site yet...

Comment: [Sounds familiar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Death_Day)

Comment: I vaguely a story, probably written in the 1940s, which is set in a cocktail party. The reader eventually catches on to the fact that the same snippets of conversation keep repeating. I remember that one of the snippets had to do with Disney's "Fantasia", which is why I think it's from the '40s. It wasn't a wild party at all - and the time loop seemed pretty tight - so it doesn't resemble the description in all particulars.

Comment: @Solinv: Just to note, having your question closed as a duplicate is not a censure or an indication that it is a bad question. :) This is basically a bookkeeping thing so that different questions with different details for the same story all route to the same place, which makes the database more efficient.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots. Ok, thanks for the clarification. Makes sense. As long as this version stays online, even as "duplicate", it can help others find it through this angle. And the original question didn't link to the story (I just added it in the comments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**: after browsing through the titles of this anthology (which comprises more than 20 volumes...), it sounds the story could be *Now is forever* by Thomas M. Disch. There's actually a central premise : a new machine, the "Reprostat", allows for infinite duplication of everything. So people just slide into this hedonistic lifestyle, duplicate their own bodies, and live this never-ending party, consequences-free. So in fact it's not a time loop, more an "unlimited resources" setup, but with similar results. What struck me most (and stayed in my memory) was the description of this carefree, happily decadent lifestyle.

Anybody read it ? I couldn't find any link online, if anybody has one... Thanks :)

**UPDATE 2**: providing the link to the story kindly provided by @user14111 :
https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?493694

Originally published in Amazing Stories in march 1964, under the pen name of Dobbin Thorpe.

Comment: Try to find this anthology of his stories Under Compulsion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under_Compulsion

Comment: The story is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Amazing_Stories_v38n03_1964-03_aMouse#page/n83/mode/2up).

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?493694

Comment: This actually occurred to me but I discounted it as it wasn't a time loop. [See this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94553/unpleasant-uses-of-replicator-3d-printer/94563)

Comment: @user14111 Thanks for the link. I was trying to find that Amazing Stories issue but couldn't locate it

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thanks for the tip. I guess it's customary, but I don't know, I would feel strange to give myself credit for answering my own question. But apparently somebody did it for me (crediting me for the answer). Well, hopefully the info will benefit some other curious wanderers as well ;)

Comment: @Fruitbat You were right. For some reason, what stuck with me what this "forever party", and I completely zapped out the replicator. The asker's description in the other question you linked to is way more accurate than mine. That being said, it could be argued (for the sake of argument), that they have indeed created a time loop of sorts for themselves by indefinitely recreating their own bodies at the same point in time.

Comment: @Solinv: Until you accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark, it's still marked as unanswered. :) If it makes you feel better, you don't get any points for accepting your own answer. It just lets people know that the question has been answered so if someone is browsing the site looking for this story, they'll know it has a good answer.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Ok, done :)